# Can ClickHouse convert the string in format 'DD-MMM-YYYY' to Date?

Tags: clickhouse

Is there a function like that in clickhouse? Similar to mysql's [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

I need to convert '04-Jun-2021' to '2021-06-04'

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [parseDateTime32BestEffort](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions/#parsedatetime32besteffort):

```sql
SELECT
    '04-Jun-2021' AS str,
    parseDateTime32BestEffort(str) AS dateTime,
    toDate(dateTime) AS date

┌─str─────────┬────────────dateTime─┬───────date─┐
│ 04-Jun-2021 │ 2021-06-04 00:00:00 │ 2021-06-04 │
└─────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────┘
```